# Create React App is throwing "Loading chunk # failed" error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am building a `CRA App` using `npm run build` and then when i try to deploy it or when i use `serve build/` i get the following error.

```
Error: "Loading chunk 1 failed.
(error: http://localhost:5000/admin/static/js/1.d30b6723.chunk.js)"

react-dom.production.min.js:4406
Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Loading chunk 1 failed.
(error: http://localhost:5000/admin/static/js/1.d30b6723.chunk.js)"

es6.promise.js:145
```

New to react, How do i solve this? Using `Core UI` as my template.

The network in console is giving 404.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but I think it was issue with your homepage and scope in your package.json file. Mostly it was not set so your build was unable to find the js file.